# Perforce: How to mark for delete files present in depot but not in workspace?

Tags: perforce

We have a code base which is downloaded from internet (GitHub repository). Updating process is following:

1. p4 Checkout existing version
2. Download new version from internet and extract it over old version
3. p4 Revert unchanged files
4. p4 Submit changes

Problem with this approach is that files which are not present in downloaded repo (removed from GitHub repo) are still present in file system and considered as unchanged. Revert unchanged files will revert them back and keep in depot/workspace. This is particular problem for Java files since we compile by specify root folder. Remaining file is unreferenced in new source but you can't see it.

`p4 clean` has option **-d**

> Deleted files: Find those files **in the depot** that do not exist in your workspace and **add them to the workspace**.

but I am looking for opposite

> Find those files in the workspace that do not exist in your depot and **delete** them from the depot.

If I delete whole folder structure from file system, workspace goes out of sync.
How to find/mark for delete files which are not present in new folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

This is my typically recommended workflow for this use case:

1. Start with an empty workspace
2. Extract the current version of the tree into the workspace
3. `p4 flush` to the revision you want to use as the base (if you've made no changes to this branch on the Perforce side, you can just use the default `#head`)
4. `p4 reconcile` to open all files for the appropriate action
5. `p4 submit`

To elaborate on step 3: the "base" should be whatever revision the two trees were last in sync at.  If this is a one-way operation, it's always just the latest revision (which came directly from github).  If you're making changes on both sides, you should have a separate branch on the Perforce side for your github imports, and **only** use it for imports; then do one-way merges from there into your development mainline so you can resolve differences with all the right history tracking.

Comment: We are not modifying downloaded repositories. We keep them for referencing because build server is not allowed to fetch anything from internet. Only approved OSS components/versions could be used during build.

Comment: Cool, in that case this is all very straightforward; just do a regular `p4 flush` in step 3 (the head is the default) and everything ought to work.